# Keyboard shortcut to convert selection to uppercase (or lowercase) in the atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

What is the keyboard shortcut to convert the currently selected text to uppercase (or lowercase) in the Atom editor?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

On Windows and Linux:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> for uppercase
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for lowercase

On Mac:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> for uppercase
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for lowercase

Comment: You could also use the generic "ctrl + shift + p" shortcut, and then type "uppercase" or "lowercase" to access the corresponding command.

Comment: For linux use `Ctrl + K` then ( `Ctrl + L` for lower `Ctrl + U` for  uppercase)

Comment: What does `Cmd + K` or `Ctrl + K` mean?

Comment: @mCeviker It means press the keyboard keys. `Cmd` is the key labelled "cmd" on a Mac. `Ctrl` is the key labelled "ctrl". When we write it with a "+" sign it means "Hold `Ctrl` and press `K` at the same time. This is a convention that is often used for keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Yes of course I know that means press some keyboard keys, but for example cmd + u  'makes uppercase' , I am asking what does 'cmd + k' do?

Comment: @mCeviker oh, right :) (I answered the question as if for keyboard n00bs) ... To answer YOUR question, `Cmd + K` means "enter command mode" or something like that. I can't find an authoritative source. But there are other commands that are activated by first hitting `Cmd + K`.

Answer (score 6):

**For Windows OS**

For Uppercase **CTRL + K + U**

For Lowercase **CTRL + K + L**