# Keyboard shortcut to convert selection to capitalized case in the atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, capitalization

What is the keyboard shortcut to convert the currently selected text to capitalized case in the Atom editor?

For example. If I was to select `brown fox` and I would hit the keyboard shortcut I'm looking for, it would become `Brown Fox`.

I know <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> exists for converting to uppercase and lowercase. I hope for something like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exist.

Related: [Keyboard shortcut to convert selection to uppercase (or lowercase) in the atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790154/keyboard-shortcut-to-convert-selection-to-uppercase-or-lowercase-in-the-atom-e)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found this package: https://atom.io/packages/change-case

After installing it, I opened the config editor (there's a button in the package manager). Then in .atom>packages>change-case>keymaps>change-case.cson I changed the file from:

```
'.platform-darwin atom-workspace':
  'cmd-k cmd-c': 'change-case:camel'
  'cmd-k cmd-s': 'change-case:snake'

'.platform-win32 atom-workspace':
  'ctrl-k ctrl-c': 'change-case:camel'
  'ctrl-k ctrl-s': 'change-case:snake'
```

To this:

```
'.platform-darwin atom-workspace':
  'cmd-k cmd-c': 'change-case:camel'
  'cmd-k cmd-s': 'change-case:snake'
  'cmd-k cmd-t': 'change-case:title'

'.platform-win32 atom-workspace':
  'ctrl-k ctrl-c': 'change-case:camel'
  'ctrl-k ctrl-s': 'change-case:snake'
  'ctrl-k ctrl-t': 'change-case:title'
```

After saving the file, close Atom & restart ... worked a treat